# Error checking current user

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, error

I have two sites which haven't been changed for a week or so. Then this error message began to pop up out of nowhere. I was led to believe it was due to a custom web part, since I have a couple on my page from the SP app store. I removed them and deleted my history and cache, but the message continues to pop up. It also only pops up on the main page of both of my sites. None of my subsites or added pages have it. Could this be related to my Microsoft license with my company's IT department or something?

[image]

Comment: may be you may have a custom webpart in hidden zone so it never shows  on the UI but the JS gets executed. look at the webparts on your page using "contents" query string parameter. https://server/site/web/page.aspx?contents=1 . Delete any cusstom webparts you see on this page and try to reload the page.

Comment: I only see the ones which are displayed on my page. Nothing hidden.

Comment: Also, when I deleted the web parts and reloaded the page, the message still popped up.

Comment: So, are you seeing this error message even if you delete all the webparts from your page? if yes, try to chhange the master page also.

Comment: Yes. I am. I am unfamiliar with changing the master page. Would I go to Site Settings -> Master page, or master pages and page layouts?

Comment: master page in look and feel section

Comment: Ok...I'm there. What exactly should I change in here?

Comment: if your page is a publishing page(Pages/pagename.aspx), change the "Site Master page to "seattle.master" . If the page is a site page (/SitePages/pagename.aspx), change  the "System master page" drop down value to seattle.master

Comment: They're both already on Seattle

Comment: Ok,, try to change it to something else and try. Are you able to see this message for other user logins too? Is it ***.onmicrosoft.com account you are using?

Comment: It's a company email address. My company has SP setup where you can create your own team site. I've had other users go to the homepage and they get the same error.